# Как создать слайдер с наклонным фото

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Всем привет, подскажите как создать такой слайдер[image]

Answer (score 2):

21 век. HTML уже 5-го поколения, CSS третьего :-) Никто уже ничего не подделывает в фотошопах.

Создайте блочный эллемент и воспользуйтесь управляющей css-конструкцией `transform: rotate(45deg);`. Rotate - крутить, deg (от degrees - градус наклона) - число градусов, на которое желаете повернуть объект. Не забудьте о префиксах для различных браузеров - что во всех (или в нужных Вам) работало.

Детальное описание (официальная документация): http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

P.S. А насчет слайдера, то да - выберите по своему вкусу :-)

Answer (score 1):

Берешь обычный слайдер в интернете, создаешь в фотошопе повернутую png картинку, даешь контейнеру `position: relative`, а картинке `position: absolute`, размещаешь где тебе угодно и все.

Только смотри чтобы контейнер слайда был по высоте как картинка, а то практически во всех слайдерах есть `overflow: hidden` и оно обрежет картинку.

Если я что-то не так сказал, то дай ссылку где ты увидел этот слайдер.